# find first matches for vector of substrings in a vector of strings (duplicates in each)

Tags: r

I have two character vectors x and y, the former comprising (potential) sub strings of the latter, and both containing duplicate values. I want to return the index of the first match (if present) in y for each element in x, where the sub string is matched at the beginning of the string (cf. ^ anchor in regex), e.g:

```
x <- c("Halimid", "Halimid", "Callimid", "Diplid", "Halimid", "Cyathid")

y <- c("Bathymidae", "Bathymidae", "Halimidopidae", "Cyathidae", "Bothridae", "Cyathidae", "Diplididae", "Holothuridae")
```

some function(first match for each element of x in y if there is a match)

```
2, 2, NA, 7, 2, 4
```

i.e the function should return a vector of same length as x, containing the indices of the first match in y, or NA for elements without a match. I've already tried `base::startsWith()`, but it only works for a single substring and `pmatch()` hasn't worked for me either. I want to avoid apply and loops if possible so vectorized solutions preferred

Answer (score 1):

I can’t think of a solution without `lapply()` or `purrr::map()`, not sure
if those are acceptable for you, but they are quite simple, so here we go:

```r
x <- c("Halimid", "Halimid", "Callimid", "Diplid", "Halimid", "Cyathid")

y <- c("Bathymidae", "Bathymidae", "Halimidopidae", "Cyathidae", "Bothridae", "Cyathidae", "Diplididae", "Holothuridae")
```

Using `lapply()` and `grep()`.

```r
a <- lapply(x, function(z) grep(z, y)[1])
unlist(a)
#> [1]  3  3 NA  7  3  4
```

Using `map_dbl()` we can make the code appear a bit more simple, but it is
essentially the same.

```r
library(purrr)
map_dbl(x, ~grep(., y)[1])
#> [1]  3  3 NA  7  3  4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using traditional for loop:

```
v <- NULL
for(chr in x){
   v <- c(v,grep(chr, y)[1])
 }
v
[1]  3  3 NA  7  3  4
```